# Checkboxes inside listbox is not firing selectionchanged event in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have listbox and inside it I have taken Checkbox and within checkbox there is a textbox. ListBox's ItemSource is binded in View Model. I am trying to call selectionchanged event but it is not firing.

So I have taken ManipulationCompleted event which fires when I checks the Checkbox. But I am not getting selected item in this event. But it is strange, if I am taking textbox inside checkbox in listbox, selectionchanged event is not fired. Could you please help me why it is not working. Below is XAML for the same.

```
<ListBox x:Name="allcontacts" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                     Margin="0,5,-12,0"  Width="800" Grid.Row="1" 
                                     SelectionChanged="allcontacts_SelectionChanged"                                     
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsList,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                     ManipulationCompleted="contacts_ManipulationCompleted">
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <CheckBox x:Name="chkGroup" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                            <Image x:Name="imgFriend" 
                                                        Source="{Binding ImageUri}" 
                                                        Height="30" 
                                                        Width="30"
                                                        Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name="txtfrdName" 
                                                        Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </CheckBox>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>
```

ContactsList is observable collection of Friend class and friend class contains IsChecked and Name property which binds to CheckBox and Textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should subscribe to the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events of the Checkbox element instead of the SelectionChanged of the ListBox:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkGroup" 
    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
    Checked="HandleCheck" 
    Unchecked="HandleUnchecked"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
private void HandleCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        var selectedItem = cb.DataContext;
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

More info here: [How to: Handle the Checked Event for the CheckBox Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221404%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I want item in listbox when user checks on checkbox. Checked event does not provide me item in listbox. Could you please let me know if I can get selected item when user checks/unchecks the Checkbox or somwhow if I can subscribe the selectionchanged event.

Comment: You should use the DataContext property of the CheckBox that triggered the Checked event. I edited my answer to show you how to do that.